# How to interpret the 50Lakh limit for presumptive taxation?

Tags: income-tax, india

If someone in India has total income of 60Lakhs in FY 2021 as under:

20 Lakhs from Salary

20 Lakhs from Profession (after quitting salaried job mid-year)

20 Lakhs from capital gains

can he/she avail of presumptive taxation (section 44AD) for the income from profession (assuming it is an eligible profession)?

I ask because it says gross receipts must be under 50 Lakhs and I can't make out if that's gross for that category (profession) or overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct.

You can opt for section 44 ADA for professional income but need to pay ordinary income tax for your salary and capital gains tax as well.